# Passing around session data in PHP

Tags: php, oop, session

I have a $_SESSION var which stores simple, easily callable identifying information when a user is logged in. Even when a user is not logged in, it logs the last file visited (in case a user logs in, to return quickly to that page).

**User Logged in**

```
$_SESSION[$userid,$username,$first_name,$lastPage];
```

**User Not Logged in**

```
$_SESSION[$lastPage];
```

My chief concerns are security and ease of understanding for future programmers.

So are any of these options viable, or am I missing an option which is more secure, and very easy to understand for programmers?

1. Use the $_SESSION var, and access it in classes.
2. Use a `sessionWrapper` class to mimic the values in $_SESSION.
3. Keep only a unique identifier, and perhaps `lastPage` in the $_SESSION var. Create a `sessionWrapper` class that pulls the pertinent information from the database if this unique identifier is given.

Am I missing something here? As I write this I lean closer to option 3 but really appreciate any feedback about best practices here.

Comment: It's an array, you need to use `$_SESSION['variable'] = …`.

Comment: `$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true` ? Curious about session security? Go nuts https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet. PHP specific https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Authentication_and_Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks @MarcelKorpel - I have a working SESSION structure right now. Not wondering how to establish sessions, I just put this together to better explain what is in them now. If you have a better way to visually represent them here (symbolically), I will edit.

Comment: Option 3 is basically re-writing sessions. You've described the lifecycle of a php session. Pull the session identifier from the request, retrieve the session from storage (you say db, files are the default), and populate the session var. A session wrapper is good for DI.. but I'd assume you're no where near unit testing so far.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel it is you who does not understand. He already knows how to work in php, what he wrote is a swmbolic representation of what his array contains. Stop pestering :|

Comment: @hanzo2001 I'm not pestering. The OP says: "Not wondering" oh wait, *not* wondering. I misread the "not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought of using cookies for the `last_page` info? I'm assuming you do not have to keep everything in `$_SESSION`. OK, now for the meatball. If safety is a concern, then `$_SESSION` is ok but not the best. The problem could boil down to:

- how much security do you need
- how much are you willing to complicate things for the next-gen maintainers

**High security:** PHP sessions are saved to accessible files on the server by default, you could mitigate this by having a nicely encapsulated database inside your app. As long as it's a very simple encapsulating class then you're good to go. Your *option 3* is the a good solution.

**Low security:** If you're not willing to put down the KLOCs for your personal `$_SESSION` implementation, I think you could keep relevant info safe as you have it now, and choose cookies for less important info: `last_page` is something that is associated to a user but does not identify it, so keep them separated.

- *Option 1* for small proyects
- *Option 2* for large proyects (I use this method with some convenient and SIMPLE wrapper classes)

From my point of view you are not missing anything, you just have to take a decision and stick with it

Comment: Sure, I'd bet you have an idea already, but if you need any more help, please feel free to ask